# Android Widget: RemoteViews with TextView android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, android-widget

Recently we updated the targetSDK in our app from 21 to 23.

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
  ...

defaultConfig {
  applicationId 'com.myapp'
  minSdkVersion 15
  targetSdkVersion 23
  versionCode System.getenv("LAST_BUILD_NUMBER") as Integer ?: 1514261001
  versionName '2.6.1' + (System.getenv("APP_VERSION_SUFFIX") ?: '')
  testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
  multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Our app also has some widgets containing some TextViews like this one:

```
        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/txt_sunrise"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_classic_weather_sunrise"
           android:drawablePadding="6dp"
           android:text="-"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="@dimen/largeTextSizeAstro" />
```

The widget is built in this manner:

```
RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_large);
rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_sunrise, sunrise);
// some more code
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rv);
```

On Android 5.0 everything runs fine, but on some Android 4.x devices (I could reproduce it on some Samsung devices as well as on the Genymotion Emulator), I got an exception, when the widget should be built:

```
caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01018e a=2}
at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2074)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:342)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:912)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:578)
```

As I check the given resource-Id 0x7f01018e, it cames out that this is colorAccent defined in the app theme, which is of course not a color state list

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/grey_darker</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#111111</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/orange</item>
```

Any idea, why I got this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a deep-dive in the source code of android Textview on the specific platform and on the given line number, I found this snippet in the constructor-method:

```
case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextView_textColorLink:
     textColorLink = a.getColorStateList(attr);
     break;
```

My solution was now to add the following line to my Theme and the widget worked again:

```
<item name="android:textColorLink">@color/selector_classic_link</item>
```

Note: The selector_classic_link is a ColorStateList defined in xml.